# How can I execute a shell script when someone changes a file through FTP?

Tags: ftp, shell-script

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 Server on a VPS. I'm trying to make it so that my friend can change a configuration file for a game server through FTP, and then when that's done execute a shell script that kills the server and then restarts it. Thanks!

Comment: There are a few choices of ftp-server - which one do you have installed?

Comment: To echo what @albal said, more details (game, $SHELL, etc) are helpful! Depending on how much information you need the answer provided may get you started.

Answer (score 0):

### Run a script post-upload

[`pureftpd`](https://www.pureftpd.org/project/pure-ftpd) provides [`pure-uploadscript`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/pure-uploadscript.8.html), which you could use to restart the game process:

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> If  Pure-FTPd  is  compiled with `--with-uploadscript` (default in binary
>          distributions), and if the `-o` (or  `--uploadscript`)  is  passed  to  the
>          server,  a named pipe called `/var/run/pure-ftpd.upload.pipe` is created.
>          You    will    also     notice     an     important     file     called
>          `/var/run/pure-ftpd.upload.lock`, used for locking.
>          After a successful upload, the file name is written to the pipe.
>          `pure-uploadscript`  reads  this pipe to automatically run any program or
>          script to process the newly uploaded file.

*(from the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/pure-uploadscript.8.html))*

Use this to detect a change in the game config file[s] (the uploaded/modified file is passed in as the first argument to the script- `$1`), and if they are changed, restart the game server.

Otherwise you could use some `bash` scripting and `cron` to check the `mtime` of the config file and restart the server if it changes to something newer. Or you could get *really fancy* and hook `inotify` via something like [`inotify-tools`](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki); but that is likely overkill for this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using, or will use [proftpd](http://www.proftpd.org/) then you can use the module [mod_exec](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_exec.html) and execute a command when the file is changed.

However, I do not recommend this - you should use a controlled remote session to restart the service.  This could be done with a user of least privilege and then correct specification of the [sudoers](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos) file to only allow access to the service of interest.